# Using INDIRECT on VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vlookup

how to put file path based on cell value and lead me to INDIRECT but I got error can execute with right code, can someone guide me on this, I got 500+ vlookup that I need to change the file path every restaurant because their consumption was saved in different folders, I want to fix 1 cell that it will be served as file path if I paste the directory path all vlookup will update. here is the example

> =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A143,'C:\BOOTDRV\AlohaTS\RptExport[02.csv]02'!$C:$D,2,0),0)

If I put values on A1, C:\Documents and Settings\MPC\My Documents\Downloads\PMIX

Then all VLOOKUP code will update to

> =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A143,'C:\Documents and Settings\MPC\My Documents\Downloads\PMIX[02.csv]02'!$C:$D,2,0),0)

Comment: You have only given us one example. What does the line above look like? Is it: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A142,'C:\Documents and Settings\MPC\My Documents\Downloads\PMIX[02.csv]02'!$C:$D,2,0),0)`?

Comment: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A143,'C:\BOOTDRV\AlohaTS\RptExport\[02.csv]02'!$C:$D,2,0),0)

i want to change C:\BOOTDRV\AlohaTS\RptExport using cell value on A1

Comment: I know. But what is the formula on row 142.

Comment: sorry it was may error. All formula are A143, only 1 row.

Comment: ow i see you mean the formula above a143 which is a142, yes your right same as a143.

Comment: Ok. Indirect alone will not solve your problem. That is why I'm trying to figure out what else may solve it. It seems to me as if you edit the first formula you can just fill down and they will all be correct. But since we don't have enough about the sheet it's hard to know.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A143,'C:\BOOTDRV\AlohaTS\RptExport[02.csv]02'!$C:$D,2,0),0)
```

With indirect:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A143,INDIRECT(B2),2,0),0)
```

Where in B2 you will have: "C:\BOOTDRV\AlohaTS\RptExport[02.csv]02'!$C:$D" (without quotes). You can use any cell you want of course. So in the end you could have one column dedicated to directories and second to VLOOKUPs. The advantage of this solution is that if there is a logic in the way how workbooks are named, you can use formula to generate the directories (for example if they are named 01.csv, 02.csv etc.).

By the way you will have to have that workbook open for it to work, indirect works only in opened workbooks. So I advice to open them in bulk, rewrite cells looking for data in opened ones as values (once they update), close them and open next few and repeat this until you have it all updated. It is the easiest way (if you don't know how to use macros).

Comment: Thanks for the Reply sir Daniel, what if i want to change C:\Documents and Settings\MPC\My Documents\Downloads\PMIX\ only and not including [02.csv]02 because i need to change the Directory path only not the file name or the sheet.

Comment: @RyanAustria Is there any logic in this directory? Like maybe these reports would be located in subfolders of one common folder? Or do you have somewhere a list of these directories? Could you send me few examples please?

Comment: I would try to explain the problem. We have a program that counts our consumption for a day then extract the consumption into a 01.csv (Day 1 of the Month) But the problem is we have 44 branches and they have different file path assign to there personal computer for there consumption (01.csv,02.csv etc..) and not all personel on that branch is knowledgeable how to change file path directory on all formulas.

Comment: the solution that i Found is i will instruct them to Right click on the File 01.csv and then copy the Directory Path: then Paste is on A1 cell (which it will change all the filepatch base on there personal preferences where they save there consumption)

it was much easy than edit 500+ plus vlookup. I know i can use CTRL+H to replace the directory path but can i do this in formula.

Comment: @RyanAustria agreed, if you dont have a list of directories this is hard to achieve just with formulas without any manual work.

Comment: so no possible way to change Directory path folder(not including the filename of the .csv) on Vlookup using cell. well may need to remote there pc and use replace command. Sad

Comment: @RyanAustria Well if you have list of those locations, you can put them in column C and then in B1 you would have `=C1&"RptExport[02.csv]02'!$C:$D"` and apply this for the whole column; this would give you the directory in column B and you could use that in INDIRECT in column A VLOOKUP. But from your comment I understood that you don't have such list.

Comment: Good news Sir Daniel Maczak, 

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,INDIRECT("'"&G9&"'!C:D"),2,0),0)

to get the G9 value i use to cells 

G1= D:\BOOTDRV\AlohaTS\RptExport\
G2 = [01.csv]01
G9 = =(G4&""&G6)

Which is i can know change the Directory path without touching the filename and sheet just the directory path.

May problem is Using INDIRECT will cannot save the last result, return value of 0, anyway that I can get the last value like vlookup. then will not update unless reopen the file.

Comment: @RyanAustria yes, that is exactly what I mention in my answer: "By the way you will have to have that workbook open for it to work, **INDIRECT works only in opened workbooks**. So I advice to open them in bulk, rewrite cells looking for data in opened ones as values (once they update), close them and open next few and repeat this until you have it all updated. It is the easiest way (if you don't know how to use macros)."